# Error despite purrr's 'otherwise' - Why is purrr/possibly's 'otherwise' not triggered?

Tags: r, purrr

I am scraping content from websites. For this I iterate over links. If an error occurs,  `purrr`'s `possibly` adverb should keep the process going, and place a "missing" (or "NA_character") as a result.

The code below works as intended when the site linked to is not existing, i.e. the output is "missing";
However, if the site linked to exists, but the element which I am trying to extract from the site does not exist, the function throws an error despite having defined a value for '`otherwise`'.

To me this is surprising, since the documentation states that

> ' `possibly` : wrapped function uses a default value ( `otherwise` ) whenever an error occurs.'

Any idea why this is happening? I understand that i could modify the function accordingly (e.g. check for the length of the returned object). But I do not understand why the '`otherwise`' value was not used.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.0.4
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.0.4
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.0.4
library(rvest)
#> Warning: package 'rvest' was built under R version 4.0.4
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rvest'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     guess_encoding

# possibly with wrong links when scraping site ----------------------------
#see https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/409

sample_data <- tibble::tibble(
  link = c(
    #link ok, selected item exists
    "https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG/XXVII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00068/index.shtml#tab-Sten.Protokoll",
    #link not ok
    "https://www.wrong-url.foobar",
    #link ok, selected item does not exist on site
    "https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG/XXVII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00094/index.shtml#tab-Sten.Protokoll"
    
           )
)


fn_get_link_to_records <- function(link_to_overview_sessions) {
  
print(link_to_overview_sessions)
    
link_to_overview_sessions %>% 
    rvest::read_html() %>% 
    rvest::html_elements("a") %>% 
    rvest::html_attr("href") %>% 
    enframe(name = NULL,
            value = "link_to_text") %>% 
    filter(str_detect(link_to_text, regex("\\/NRSITZ_\\d+\\/fnameorig_\\d+\\.html$"))) %>% 
    mutate(link_to_text=glue::glue("https://www.parlament.gv.at/{link_to_text}")) %>% 
    pull()
}


sample_data %>% 
  mutate(link_to_text=map_chr(link, 
                              possibly(fn_get_link_to_records,
                                       otherwise=NA_character_)))
#> [1] "https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG/XXVII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00068/index.shtml#tab-Sten.Protokoll"
#> [1] "https://www.wrong-url.foobar"
#> [1] "https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG/XXVII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00094/index.shtml#tab-Sten.Protokoll"
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `link_to_text`.
#> x Result 3 must be a single string, not a vector of class `glue/character` and of length 0
#> i Input `link_to_text` is `map_chr(link, possibly(fn_get_link_to_records, otherwise = NA_character_))`.

sample_data %>% 
  mutate(link_to_text=map_chr(link, 
                              possibly(fn_get_link_to_records,
                                       otherwise="missing")))
#> [1] "https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG/XXVII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00068/index.shtml#tab-Sten.Protokoll"
#> [1] "https://www.wrong-url.foobar"
#> [1] "https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG/XXVII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00094/index.shtml#tab-Sten.Protokoll"
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `link_to_text`.
#> x Result 3 must be a single string, not a vector of class `glue/character` and of length 0
#> i Input `link_to_text` is `map_chr(link, possibly(fn_get_link_to_records, otherwise = "missing"))`.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

UPDATE: I added the output below to make the unexpected result (last chunk) clearer.

```r
sample_data[1:2,] %>% 
  mutate(link_to_text=map_chr(link, 
                              possibly(fn_get_link_to_records,
                                       otherwise="missing")))
#> [1] "https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG/XXVII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00068/index.shtml#tab-Sten.Protokoll"
#> [1] "https://www.wrong-url.foobar"
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   link                                  link_to_text                            
#>   <chr>                                 <chr>                                   
#> 1 https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG~ https://www.parlament.gv.at//PAKT/VHG/X~
#> 2 https://www.wrong-url.foobar          missing
sample_data[3, ] %>% 
  mutate(link_to_text=map_chr(link, 
                              possibly(fn_get_link_to_records,
                                       otherwise="missing")))
#> [1] "https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG/XXVII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00094/index.shtml#tab-Sten.Protokoll"
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `link_to_text`.
#> x Result 1 must be a single string, not a vector of class `glue/character` and of length 0
#> i Input `link_to_text` is `map_chr(link, possibly(fn_get_link_to_records, otherwise = "missing"))`.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: For me it works as expected with 3 values as "missing" without any error. What is your `packageVersion('purrr')` ? I am on `[1] ‘0.3.4’`.

Comment: It's easy enough to test, run this: `possibly( function(){stop("FOO!")}, otherwise=NA, quiet=TRUE )()` .

Comment: @RonakShah I am on 0.3.4. as well. I updated the question above to show that the first 2 links result in expected output; the last one however is surprising to me.

Comment: I just realised in `fn_get_link_to_records` function there is no `html_elements` function in `rvest`, also `read_html` is not from `rvest` but `xml2`. I am not sure how it is working for you but even for first 2 values I get both of them as `missing` because of those errors.

Comment: html_elements was introduced with rvest 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from `map_chr` but you have `possibly` wrapped around `fn_get_link_to_records` function. If you run `fn_get_link_to_records(sample_data$link[3])` you'll see the URL get's printed and nothing is returned and no error is generated. However, `map_chr` cannot change this  empty output to character value hence you get the error. Instead of `map_chr` if you use `map` you'll see it works.

```
sample_data[3,] %>% 
  mutate(link_to_text= map(link, fn_get_link_to_records))

#[1] #"https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG/XXVII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00094/index.shtml#tab-Sten.Protokoll"
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  link                                                                                     link_to_text
#  <chr>                                                                                    <list>      
#1 https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG/XXVII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00094/index.shtml#tab-Sten.Pro… <glue [0]>
```

but `link_to_text` is empty. The solution as you already know is check length of output value and return `NA` or generate an error inside `fn_get_link_to_records` functions for such cases which will be handled using `possibly`.